# NumPy - Image (matrix) thresholding using an intensity value matrix.

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, matrix

I need to segment out anomalies in a greyscale image. In a certain place in my algorithm, I compute a matrix that contains the known pixel intensities that I need to set to zero. How would I do this?

For example: 
The computed pixel intensities: 
(array([ 94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106,
       107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119,
       120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132,
       133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145,
       146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151]),) 
The picture is of size (480,640) :
Printed it gives: 
 [[ 86  90  97 ..., 142 152 157]
 [ 85  89  97 ..., 145 154 158]
 [ 83  87  95 ..., 154 158 159]
 ...,
 [130 134 139 ..., 156 154 154]
 [130 134 140 ..., 154 153 152]
 [130 134 141 ..., 154 153 152]]

I realize that for each pixel I could go through the intensity matrix. This would, however, be too expensive. NumPy experts I need your help!

Comment: The pixel intensities that I want to set to zero are computed on the flow and can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set to zero all pixels in an image array which have values from 91 to 151, inclusive, use:

```
import numpy as np
newimage = np.where(np.logical_and(91<=oldimage, oldimage<=151), 0, oldimage)
```

To set to zero all pixels in an image array whose values belong to some array `vct`, use:

```
newimage = np.where(np.in1d(oldimage, vct).reshape(oldimage.shape), 0, oldimage)
```

#### Example

Suppose we have an `oldimage` like this:

```
In [12]: oldimage
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

And we have a list of numbers called `vct`:

```
In [13]: vct
Out[13]: array([3, 5])
```

Let's set to zero all pixels in `oldimage` that are also in `vct`:

```
In [14]: newimage = np.where(np.in1d(oldimage, vct).reshape(oldimage.shape), 0, oldimage)

In [15]: newimage
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: The pixel intensities that I want to set to zero are computed on the flow and can be different. Can I maybe come up with conditions based on a vector of numbers. Say more than 91 and less than 151?

Comment: @Talha I just added to the answer a version that handles a condition based on an arbitrary vector of numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I had actually proceeded with writing a function with a for loop that would find bounds but this seems like it is the vectored solution. I will check which algorithm is faster and by how much in an hour or so.

Comment: Turns out the in1d function doesn't scale so well with large arrays. With the in1d function I get about 6 FPS. With my bound finding algorithm and the threshold method I get about 90 FPS.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
oI[ (oI >93) & (oI < 152)  ] = 0
```

should do I think...

According to your question, you want to have specific *non-contiguous* numbers in an array. That is best handled by a `map`-`reduce` algorithm. Let us say you want the following numbers to be set to `0`:

```
numList = np.array([2, 15, 100, 56])
```

Then you can set a mask like so, and reduce them to a single mask:

```
mask     = (oI == 2)|(oI == 15)|(oI == 100)|(oI == 56)
oI[mask] = 0
```

This is clearly not a good solution for a big list of numbers. So you can do ...

```
mask = reduce( lambda m, n: m|n ,[ oI == i for i in numList]) 
oI[mask] = 0
```

If it is *contiguous*, like between `a` and `b`, then you just use the earlier approach ...

```
mask = (oI > a) & (oI < b)
```

Of course you can combine the masks in any set of *contiguous* and *non contiguous* sets of numbers. Just `|` them.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: The pixel intensities that I want to set to zero are computed on the flow and can be different. Can I maybe come up with conditions based on a vector of numbers. Say more than 91 and less than 151?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. My values will be contiguous. But I might receive two contiguous lists. Say [3,4,5,6,7,90,91,92,93,94]. How would I find out the endpoints of these contiguous values ([a = 1, b =7][a = 90, b = 94] in this example).